# Chrome Extension: Replace context menu item action

Tags: google-chrome-extension

is it possible to replace the action of an existing item in the context menu in Chrome.  Simple example, every time I press "Inspect Element", it opens another developer tool extension instead of the default.

Answer (score 2):

It is not: at the moment, devtools APIs only function if the web inspector is open. There's no mechanism to open the web inspector for a user, it has to be her explicit choice.

That said, it sounds reasonable to give an extension the ability to hook into an element's context menu. That might be a good idea for an extension to the existing devtools or Context Menu APIs. Would you mind filing a request at http://new.crbug.com/? I'll make sure it lands in the correct queue.